# Selecting polygon based on value present in field using QGIS Graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, polygon, openstreetmap, qgis-modeler, select-by-attribute

I have a layer (polygons) of municipalities and I need to select just one polygon based on their name (e.g. *'venice'* this value is present as a value in the field `"COMUNE"` ) because this polygon must be the input for the quick OSM polygon to download the OSM dataset for this particular area.

So basically I need the list of municipalities as a parameter for the input for the selection.

Comment: If the question is indeed about QGIS modeler, you should state that clearly in your question body (and tags as well), not just the title.

Comment: Ok sorry for bad explanation. Yes I'm trying to build a model where I select first my municipality and then automatic download the OSM data based on this polygon.  How can provide the basic model ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1e3rDFuplYoHZcp6dDwpYk99bL6sS2cs4?usp=sharing

Comment: unlocked please try now

Comment: Ok just for my understanding you can download the model from cloud but you can't open or you aren't able to download the data ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1e3rDFuplYoHZcp6dDwpYk99bL6sS2cs4?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hi I received and provided access

Comment: OK, I could download the model, but it is not valid, see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLIE1.png I'm not really sure what exactly the model should do as I don't see any OSM query?

Comment: Hi I re-upload again the model with the query for osm "highway " and select data base on extracted polygon based on query  "COMUNE"  =  'Saonara' but the osm query doesn't works also if the polygon is extracted and if I use this polygon as input for the quickOSM plugin Im avble to download the data but the goal is do this in automatic way